# Does pytorch have function to calculate correlation coefficient matrix like numpy.corrcoef ()

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Does pytorch have function to calculate correlation coefficient matrix like `numpy.corrcoef ()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[torch.corrcoef](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.corrcoef.html) is the equivalent function of [numpy.corrcoef](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html).

`torch.corrcoef` as `numpy.corrcoef`: Estimates the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient matrix of the variables given by the input matrix, where rows are the variables and columns are the observations.

```py
import numpy as np
import torch

# generate random array and tensor equivalent
X = np.random.rand(15, 10)
X_torch = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float32)

# compute corrcoef using those functions
Z1 = np.corrcoef(X)
Z2 = torch.corrcoef(X_torch)

# The mean abs difference is less than 1e-5
print(np.abs(Z1 - Z2.numpy()).mean())
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

`fastai` (implemented heavily in pytorch) provides a suite of correlation coefficients including Pearson, Spearman, and Matthews (which probably is not what you want).  `fastai`'s documentation lists all of the stored commands [here](https://docs.fast.ai/metrics.html). You can use them via hooks during Pytorch training.

Answer (score 0):

Look up this link:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.corrcoef.html
I guess it is the same function, I am unsure if it outputs the same results but it should be what you were looking for.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31296891)